# Tache rojo en nuevo projecto java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

apenas estoy en el mundo de la programación y desde que estoy en Atom, no se me ejecutan los programas.... me cambie a eclipse pero aparece este tachecito rojo en los proyectos de java eclipse, ya no se que hacer, temo que si cambio de IDE también tenga algún problema parecido. Ya cheque varios tutoriales pero no se que pasa.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo he usado neatbeans y eclipse y ambos me abren el proyecto. El ide no deberia ser un problema

Comment: Ya no me salio despues de instalar NetBeans IDE, sin embargo los demás IDE`s ya no he checado, pero en lo que avanzo más de este mundo, me quedaré con Netbeans, muchas gracias a los que me repondieron

Answer (score 3):

Como comentan en otras respuestas, el error tiene que ver con la versión de Java que estás utilizando para compilar. Sin embargo, la causa no es que la versión 15 sea incorrecta o esté mal, sino que faltan ficheros para poder compilar con esta versión.

Hasta la versión 8 de Java, los ficheros de código se agrupaban en paquetes, teniendo que declarar al principio de cada fichero, a qué paquete pertenecía. En la versión 9 se añadió el concepto de módulo, que a su vez contiene paquetes, y estos contienen clases (entre otras entidades Java).

Entonces, para poder compilar con la versión 15 de Java (en realidad la 9 o superior), te hace falta añadir la declaración y uso de los paquetes de tu aplicación, y cómo estos se relacionan. Para ello existe el fichero module-info.java.

Puedes encontrar más información sobre los módulos en [Understanding Java 9 Modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).

Comentarte que la recomendación de utilizar Java 8 (a veces aparece como 1.8) es la más sencilla de las dos soluciones que hay, que son:

- Añadir la información sobre los módulos en el proyecto.
- Usar una versión anterior a Java 9, como Java 8, donde no existen módulos.

Answer (score 0):

esto me ha pasado muchas veces trabajando con eclipse, y siempre o casi siempre suele ser tema de versiones. Esto es fácil, has de ponerte encima del proyecto, click derecho y has de buscar la opción build path, ahi veras la pestaña de librerías, dependencias y todas las herramientas usadas por tu proyecto. Lo que tendrás que hacer es buscar el apartado donde aparezca la librería con la versión de Java que usa ese proyecto, y intentaría siendo tu probar con la 1.8. Espero que te sirva!